# Lanczos Splines

Tags: interpolation

to start I would like to say I do not have much knowledge about this topic.
What I would like to know is if it is possible to calculate the blending functions of lanczos resample filter.

In: [Catmull-Rom splines](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~462/projects/assn2/assn2/catmullRom.pdf)

As it is demonstrated in the bottom of this paper, the weight of each coefficient can be formulated with the presented blending photos.

How does one can use the same logic to calculate the weights of the Lanczos?

Comment: Of course. The weighting functions are $\text{sinc}$ windowed by the main lobe of a larger $\text{sinc}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling All linear interpolation formulas can be seen as linear combinations of basis functions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am sorry, but can you be more detailed on how I am able to do it? Or direct me to some kind of example?

Comment: Care to read the Wikipedia article.